Creating a JWT Token using an RS256 Algorithm with a CNG Certificate in .NET 3.5
I'm currently limited to the Framework I can use and that is .NET 3.5.
I don't have much experience with using certificates and with the framework limitations I'm pretty stumped.
I have a certificate containing a private key, but its not a Crypto API Key, its a CNG key, so I need to be able to extract the private key from this and then create a JWT Token using RS256 Algorithm.
Currently I'm using
X509Certificate2Collection cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprintDach, false);
if (cers.Count > 0)
{
    certificate = cers[0];
    
};
var exportedKey = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);

But when I expand my certificate the private key field says, "Invalid provider type", but I can still export it.
With 3.5 I couldn't find any compatible JWT packages that I could use, so I tried to create an JWT Encoder by following the first reply in this link
Is there any JSON Web Token (JWT) example in C#?
But when I do this
var exportedKey = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
return JWTCreator.Encode(payload, exportedKey, JwtHashAlgorithm.RS256);

It does not give the correct JWT token and I'm not able to correctly Authorize my connection to a website. He did mention its only 95% done so I didn't know how to get it fully integrated and working correctly.
Migrating to a different framework is not an option.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I need to fix to get this to work.

I agree with @bartonjs that .NET 3.5 is deadly outdated, but if the compatibility is a requirement, then you have to go hard way: use p/invoke over native CryptoAPI functions. You will need three functions:

CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey
NCryptSignHash
NCryptFreeObject

The flow is quite straightforward:

Call CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey function by passing certificate handle and specify CRYPT_ACQUIRE_ALLOW_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG in dwFlags parameter. phCryptProvOrNCryptKey parameter will receive the handle to private key.
Calculate a hash over your data using plain .NET code. You should get a byte array that represents the hash
Call NCryptSignHash by passing private key handle acquired in step 1 and hash data acquired in step 2. pbSignature out parameter will receive signature.
Cleanup all unmanaged allocations using NCryptFreeObject function

Unfortunately, I don't have a ready example, but 10 years ago I wrote a PowerShell script that does exactly same thing using techniques described above: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/sign-data-with-ecc-cng-certificate.aspx. Although the article is about PowerShell, it should be easily translated to C# code.

After I run the following functions, would I just export certificate and send it to the JWT encoder ( as I've mentioned in the question).
Also looks like my certificate still says "Invalid provider type specified" for the private key.

You don't need  (and you can't) to read cert.PrivateKey property. You pass only certificate handle to these functions.

I'm able to pass the certificate handle to these functions without any issues. Everything is running correctly.
But the issue with .Net 3.5 is I had to manually add a JWT encoder which takes the private key as input. I didn't know how I'd pass the input to that after this process.

You have to modify referenced JWT encoder code (given the code is already provided) by replacing their signing code with your own that uses NCryptSignHash function.


I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I need to fix to get this to work.

You need to move to .NET Framework 4.6 or higher to have CNG keys work with certificates. (4.6 for RSA, 4.6.1 for ECDSA, 4.6.2 for DSA)  (Or any .NET Core version, or .NET 5+)

Migrating to a different framework is not an option.

Then your only alternative is to get the key migrated to CAPI and update the certificate to refer to the CAPI location.

I'm currently limited to the Framework I can use and that is .NET [Framework] 3.5.

.NET Framework 3.5 came out in 2007, and had a Service Pack in 2008, it hasn't gained any new features in 16 years.
Any version of Windows that's still in support will have at least .NET Framework 4.6.2, and probably 4.8 or 4.8.1.  But, if you're a library that's called by a legacy application there's not much you can do.

I tried to use 4.6 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 but I still had the error as System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Invalid provider type specified.'
It seemed to go away in .NET 8.
